# Best place to hook path conversion in to Emacs under Windows

Tags: shell, emacs, path, elisp, hook

I use [GNU Emacs on Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/efaq-w32.html) with [git-bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) for unix tools like `locate`, `grep` and `find`. The git-bash tools spit out paths in the following form:

```
/c/path/to/file/file.txt
```

Emacs needs for functions like `find-file`, `find-file-at-point` or (with the `helm`-package) the function `helm-find-file` its paths in the form

```
c:/path/to/file/file.txt
```

I wrote a converter-function which converts the former into the latter and I hooked it via `defadvice` in `expand-file-name`. This works reasonable well (e.g. in my initial use case to make `helm-locate` cooperate with the git-bash `locate`).

However in some cases it does not work, like in interactive use of `find-file-at-point`. So my question is what is a more universal place to hook this converter in to make even interactive calls work properly?

Comment: [cygwin-mount](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el) seems to add a pattern to `file-name-handler-alist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jenesaisquoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415684/jenesaisquoi)'s comment brought me to [cygwin-mount.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el). I tried it with *gitbash* - and it magically works!

The reason is that *gitbash* provides a similar `mount` command as *cygwin* does and *gitbash*'s paths are *cygwin* paths as well.

Just make sure the gitbash binaries are in emacs' `PATH` environment variable.